# What do I change to my PHP code for the gallery in the repeater to work?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

With ACF, there is an option to add galleries within repeater fields. My question however, is how I write the PHP that can showcase this gallery.

I tried finding similar questions, which solutions didn't work for me. Also I tried finding YouTube videos and searching the ACF documentation website. Code supporting the combination for a gallery within a repeater doesn't seem to work for me.

This is the standard ACF PHP format for a repeater:

```
<?php

// check if the repeater field has rows of data
if( have_rows('repeater_field_name') ):

    // loop through the rows of data
    while ( have_rows('repeater_field_name') ) : the_row();

        // display a sub field value
        the_sub_field('sub_field_name');

    endwhile;

else :

    // no rows found

endif;

?>
```

This is the standard ACF PHP format for a gallery:

```
<?php 
$images = get_field('gallery');
$size = 'full'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
if( $images ): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach( $images as $image_id ): ?>
            <li>
                <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image_id, $size ); ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I hope I can somehow comebine the two to get the expected result. My PHP knowledge isn't great however. So all the help would be welcome.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please do a `echo '<pre>' . print_r( get_field('your_repeater_field_here'), TRUE) . '</pre>`;` where you call the repeater and add that output (it'll be an array) to this question? I think being able to see your data with your real field names would be helpful.

Comment: I know see I can't add any fields.  This is the PHP I am trying to add: <?php the_field('woning_postcode'); ?> Nothing shows up on the frontend.

Comment: `the_field` echoes out whatever data is present. Like I asked, please add the array. That way we can focus on one issue and narrow it down. Also, where are you trying to output this? You might need to pass the post id to the `the_field('field_name', post_id_here)`

Comment: I added: echo '<pre>' . print_r( get_field('woning_postcode'), TRUE) . '</pre> . I am trying to output this here:  http://makelaardijjosbloemendal.nl/WordPress/woning/.

Comment: you need to wrap that in php tags `<?php put line here ?>`

Comment: I already found the problem. I bound the ACFields to posts. But apparently the PHP can't fetch MySQL fields from posts. Instead I attached the ACFields to a page. Now it works...

Answer (score 0):

You can do an alternative solution,
If you want a repeater with an image each, you can simply add an image instead of a gallery.
If you want multiple images per iteration, you can add a repeater inside a repeater.

**Solution 1:**

```
<?php
// check if the repeater field has rows of data
if( have_rows('repeater_field_name') ):
    // loop through the rows of data
    while ( have_rows('repeater_field_name') ) : the_row();
        echo '<img src="' . get_sub_field('image_field_name') . '">';
    endwhile;
else :
    // no rows found
endif;
?>
```

**Solution 2:**

```
<?php
// check if the repeater field has rows of data
if( have_rows('repeater_field_name') ):
    // loop through the rows of data
    while ( have_rows('repeater_field_name') ) : the_row();
        echo '<ul>';
        while( have_rows('repeater_sub_field_name') ) : the_row();
            echo '<li><img src="' . get_sub_field('image_field_name') . '"></li>';
        endwhile;
        echo '</ul>';
    endwhile;
else :
    // no rows found
endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems working gallery-field within repeater:

```
<?php if( have_rows('gallery') ):
    // loop through the rows of data
    while ( have_rows('gallery') ) : the_row();
                    
        $images = get_sub_field('gallery_img');
        if( $images ): ?>
                    
        <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
            <div class="glimg">
                <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="" />
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; endif;?>
   <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```